# Change default font in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, fonts

So this is a series of questions really. I would like to change the default font in `ggplot2`, and I understand the easiest way is to change the default family in `theme_gray`.

But I am puzzling how to do that. I can do this:

```
> theme_set(theme_gray(base_size = 18))
```

But I can't do this:

```
> theme_set(theme_gray(family="mono"))
Error in theme_gray(family = "mono") : unused argument (family = "mono")
```

And then when I look at the help, I wonder if I shouldn't be using `theme_update` as I am only changing one member. And then I see that it also mentions under "See also":

```
%+replace% and +.gg
```

And I wonder if I should be using those instead. Of course I could not get them to work either...

So what works? And more importantly, what ***should*** one be using to keep up in the fast changing `ggplot2` world?

Comment: I suppose the downvote is trying to get me to close this although I was hoping to get some insight on the operators.

Comment: It's an extremely important question IMHO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/ggtheme.html) have now been updated. You can use `base_family` to set the font.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(x = wt, y = mpg,
                                     colour=factor(gear))) + facet_wrap(~am)

p + theme_gray(base_family = "mono")
```

Comment: That was also not the question.

Comment: @MikeWise It answers part of your question, since you say you have the following error: `Error in theme_gray(family = "mono") : unused argument (family = "mono")`. The correct argument was `base_family`. Now, is it the "best" way, that's a matter of personal taste.

Comment: True and it might be part of more of the answer. But which one to use is not so much a matter of taste but of future intentions for the package. By so much duplicated functionality I would bet some of this is destined for the garbage bin, as my question implies. So I upvoted it.

Answer (score 4):

You can get many fonts with the package `extrafont` and use it as follows:

```
library(extrafont)
p + theme(title = element_text(family = 'Helvetica')) # whatever font you want
```